# How do I use MIN on a union column SQL

Tags: sql, postgresql, count, union, min

I'm having problems with using the MIN function in sql. I want to get a list of all the rows with the minimum value from my count function.

Here is my code:

```
SELECT land, MIN(count) as lowest 
FROM 
 (
   SELECT temp.land, count(*) 
   FROM 
    (
      SELECT grans.land FROM Grans
      UNION ALL
      SELECT grans.aland FROM Grans
    ) as temp
   GROUP BY land
   ORDER BY land
 )  as subQuery
GROUP BY land
ORDER BY land
```

At the moment I just get a table listing land and count, although count is renamed to lowest.

Comment: What RDBMS are you using? Please tag your question accordingly (This is easily solvable with windowing functions if your RDBMS supports them)

Comment: I strongly advise you to put in done example data and site is the results you want from that example data.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I would use window functions:

```
SELECT land, cnt
FROM (SELECT temp.land, count(*) as cnt,
             MIN(count(*)) OVER () as min_cnt
      FROM (SELECT grans.land FROM Grans
            UNION ALL
            SELECT grans.aland FROM Grans
           ) temp
      GROUP BY land
     ) l
WHERE cnt = min_cnt;
```

Answer (score 0):

remove group by if you just want min because if you put group by it will return all the land count that you got in your sub-query,  as in count it already made group and that is distinct

```
SELECT * 
FROM 
 (
   SELECT temp.land, count(*) as cnt
   FROM 
    (
      SELECT grans.land FROM Grans
      UNION ALL
      SELECT grans.aland FROM Grans
    ) as temp
   GROUP BY land
   ORDER BY land
 )  as subQuery

order by cnt asc
Limit 1
```

another way is

```
SELECT temp.land, count(*) as cnt
       FROM 
        (
          SELECT grans.land FROM Grans
          UNION ALL
          SELECT grans.aland FROM Grans
        ) as temp
       GROUP BY land
       having cnt in(

    SELECT min(cnt)
        FROM 
         (
           SELECT temp.land, count(*) as cnt
           FROM 
            (
              SELECT grans.land FROM Grans
              UNION ALL
              SELECT grans.aland FROM Grans
            ) as temp
           GROUP BY land
           ORDER BY land
         )  as subQuery
       )
```

and it also work

```
select * from
(
 SELECT * ,row_number() over(partition by land order by cnt) as rn 
    FROM 
     (
       SELECT temp.land, count(*) as cnt
       FROM 
        (
          SELECT grans.land FROM Grans
          UNION ALL
          SELECT grans.aland FROM Grans
        ) as temp
       GROUP BY land
       ORDER BY land
     )  as subQuery
 ) t where t.rn=1
```

Comment: Okey I think I understand what u mean but the problem is that I do want a table of all the objects in land but only the ones with the minimum value...

Comment: No issues put this on where condition

Comment: @Sara answer edited if that is mysql then use limit it and order by  you will get min land value

Comment: It gets better and better at least. Now I get the error message: argument of LIMIT must be type bigint, not type boolean
LINE 15: LIMIT cnt=1

Comment: @Sara your dbms name please ?

Comment: Do u mean PostgreSQL??

Comment: @Sara i have added 3rd solution could you please check

Comment: the first solution only gives me 1 land, but I have several objects that has the minimum value and I want to list them ALL, the second one I can't get to work.. will try the third one now